# Ubuntu Server on laptop - power off display when close lid

Tags: 11.10, server

Running Ubuntu Server 11.10 on a laptop.  I would like to find a way to have the lcd display power off when I close the lid.  Don't want to burned it out.  Tried search for an hour, but couldn't find a solution anywhere.  At least not for the server version.

Please note, this is the Server version I am asking about.  There is no GUI.

Tried searching for "ubuntu server" with words like "power management", "lid close", "display power", etc.

New:  I found a way to detect if the laptop lid is closed with the acpid daemon.  Is there any kind of power management command that will power off the display?

Comment: `vbetool dpms off` will power off the display

Answer (score 3):

Posting answer from comment above:

`vbetool dpms off` will power off the display – cscarney Dec 9 '11 at 20:52

Answer (score -1):

[image: power management settings]

found in system settings, depending on the ubuntu desktop manager you use. In this dialogue I have the option to darken the screen (and then select 0%) when closing the lid.

Comment: what did you search for within the one hour?

Comment: He probably does not have a GUI installed.

Comment: Yes, no GUI installed.